# iframe migrition and open links in the same parent tab

Tags: html, iframe

i have a iframe-

```
<div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 910px;">
```

i want that when i press a link in the iframe, the link will open in the same tab outside of the iframe.

```
<div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 910px;"> <iframe scrolling="no" src="firstopportunityonline.com/test.php"; style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 4112px; margin-top: -3825px; width: 1200px;"> <a href="page" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a> </iframe> </div>
```

what do i need to enter in the "page"?
i try to enter the page url = http://firstopportunityonline.com/forum/
and it didn't work.
the iframe give phpbb forum
WordPress widget to show parts of the forum do i need to embed some codes in some phpbb forum files to do it?

and how can i cut the bottom of the page in the iframe?
i have cut the top with `height: 4112px; margin-top: -3825px;`
but didn't get the bottom.

do i need to add a code to the parent page?
a code for the iframe page?
both are in my domain.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Target` should be defined for the links inside.. not for the `iFrame` itself.

`<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://firstopportunityonline.com/test.php" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 4680px; margin-top: -4380px; width: 1200px;">
  <a href="page" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a>
</iframe>`

Comment: I used- 
[code] <div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 910px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://firstopportunityonline.com/test.php" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 4112px; margin-top: -3825px; width: 1200px;">

<a href="page" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a>
</iframe>
</div>
[/code]
but it still not working, i get empty black window in the iframe the page in the link is to small so..thy are emptey space in the wendow..
do i need to add some code to a php file or somthing? 
thanks.

Comment: Have you replaced `page` with the link you wanted to open in `href="page"`?

Comment: [code]<a href="http://firstopportunityonline.com/forum/" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a>[/code]

is that ok?

Comment: The issue is with your styling, omit ` margin-top: -3825px;` and style in a good way.

Comment: i want the mirgration from the top so user can only see the bottom of the page in the ifram, but i want it to open a full page if thy press on a link

Comment: i use wordpress widget, dos it mater?